# Alasql Best Practices

Tags: alasql

I'm new to alasql (which is amazing). While the documentation shows you how, it doesn't provide a lot information on best practices.

To date I have simply been running queries against an array of arrays (of js objects). i haven't created a database object or table objects.

Are there performance (speed, memory, other) benefits of using database and table objects over an array of arrays?

Here is a real world example.  I have 2 sets of data that I am loading:  Employees (10 columns) and Employee Sales (5 columns), that are joined on an EmployeeID column.  Employees will be relatively small (say, 100 rows), whereas Employee Sales will have 10,000 records.  My current approach is to simply run a query where I join those 2 set of data together and end up with one big result set: 10,000 rows of data with 14 columns per row (repeating every column in the Employee data set), which I then pull data from using dynamic filters, interactivity, etc.

This big data set is stored in memory the whole time, but this has the advantage that I don't need to rerun that query over and over.  Alternatively, I could simply run the join against the 2 data sets each time I need it, then remove it from memory after.

Also, if I am joining together multiple tables, can I create indexes on the join columns to speed up performance?   I see in examples where indexes are created, but there is nothing else in the documentation. (Nothing on this page:  https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Sql).  What is the memory impact of indexes?  What are the performance impacts of insertions?

Primary keys are supported, but there is no documentation.  Does this create an index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there performance (speed, memory, other) benefits of using database and table objects over an array of arrays?

If you put indexes on your tables then - Yes - you get performance benefits. How much depends on your data.

> if I am joining together multiple tables, can I create indexes on the join columns to speed up performance?

Yes. And all other column your put into a "where" condition.